# UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE error but post_max_size and upload_max_filesize values look correct

Tags: php, file, upload, size

I am trying to upload a file which is **17569997 bytes (~16.7MB)**.

When performing error checking in my script, I inspect `$_FILES['file']['error']` which is set to 1 (`UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` - The uploaded file exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` directive in **php.ini**).

Upon finding this error, I'm `var_dumping` out some values and calling `phpinfo()` just to try and find out what is wrong. The values related to this error are:

```
post_max_size 34M
upload_max_filesize 32M
max_file_uploads 20
memory_limit 128M
```

Since `$_FILES` is actually populated, there isn't a problem with `post_max_size`. `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` is showing **17570308** which seems correct for posting the file + the rest of the form. The server is running **PHP 5.3.10** on **Ubuntu**.

Comment: Did you find those values using `phpinfo()` or directly from the php.ini? Maybe you update the ini but didn't restart the web server.

Comment: These are from phpinfo() - the Local Value and Master Value columns are both set to these values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I worked out what was happening here and this will hopefully save someone else from pulling their hair out. The disk the root file system was sitting on including `/tmp` was full due to a log filling up (5.5GB). The web root sits on another disk which had plenty of space.

I can only assume that the failure to write to `/tmp` throws the `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` error. As soon as I cleared up disk space on the root file system, the upload worked first time.